# Regex code to eliminate words separated by space?

Tags: java, regex

How to ignore the words along with the spaces using regex. Say I want to ignore the word "Java Script". Lets say
I have following data in column of a table:

```
Core Java, python
Java Script, c++
basic java, c
```

Now I want a regex code that preserves the row having the word Java but ignore the row having word "Java Script". I have following regex:

```
\b(?i)JAVA\b|\b(?i)JAVASE\b
```

This regex gets all 3 rows data. How to ignore second row and get other 2 row?

Comment: What language are you using the Regex with, SQL?

Comment: Btw, it's written *JavaScript*. No space, no problems :-)

Comment: Actually I am using Java Language.. In one column of table JavaScript is written as Java Script and due to this the row of data is displayed in the result. But I want to ignore it

Comment: Is regexp a requirement? Can't you just split it into by "\n" and then join array together ignoring second element (second row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **negative lookahead**:`(?!)` to ignore the following `" Script"`

```
Pattern.compile("\\bJava\\b(?! Script)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine how you ended up with this strange requirement, but here you go.

```
[A-Za-z ]+ava,[A-Za-z ]+\b
```

This regex will select the two lines for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^.*\bjava\b(?! \bscript\b).*
```

look for word java, but not followed by word script

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/veccQZ/2) you have also explanation there